# Automatically conda activate when in directory and source/ export

Tags: bash, terminal, conda

Goal: Automatically execute bash commands if when in directory.

For example, if I enter a `git` project directory, I'd like bash to run the following for me:

- conda activate
- export VAR_NAME=foo

---

I attempted by appending to `~/.bashrc`, but with no luck:

```
...
if [ -f "/home/me/PycharmProjects/project/" ]; then
    conda activate project_venv
    export KEY=foo
    export SECRET=bar
fi
```

Comment: Personally, I implemented a system that uses the `zsh` hook for `chpwd` (directory change) that checks for specific folders within each directory with scripts to be run. Bash doesn't have that hook, but others have shared implementations, like [this one](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57121539/570918), that could be used to similar effect.

Comment: Don't run your env_vars.sh. It will be run in a subshell environment and your exports cannot affect the calling shell's environment. Source it instead: `. ~/.../env_vars.sh`

Comment: Note: Git is not relevant here (git-bash doesn't have anything to do with Git, if that's how you got there) and the [tag:export] tag is about exporting data, not bash's `export` built-in.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Because you are exporting in a function you need to use `declare -gx`
`declare --help` will give you the best and most accurate reason why but it is because all function vars are technically `local`. The `-g` create a global exported var for a function is ignored if not in a function and the `-x` is what `export` is an alias for. `export` is just `declare -x`. You will also need to source your script files

So it will look like this

```bash
declare -gx KEY=foo
declare -gx SECRET=bar
```

```bash
cd () {
    command cd "$@" &&
    if [[ $(pwd) = '/home/me/PycharmProjects/project1' ]]; then
        conda activate project1
        source ~/miniconda3/etc/activate.d/env_vars.sh
    elif [[ $(pwd) = '/home/me/PycharmProjects/project2' ]]; then
        conda activate project2
    else
       source ~/miniconda3/etc/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh
    fi
}
```

Full disclosure I'm not sure if the `-x` is completely necessary but I do it in case of sourcing a script.

Also storing in secrets in `~/.bashrc` is a general no no as it leads to bad actors getting secrets. Ontop of slowing down your interactive shell loading times

Comment: _"Because you are exporting in a function you need to use `declare -gx`"_: There isn't such a need. Using the `export` builtin command is fine in a function.

Answer (score 3):

You can set `PROMPT_COMMAND`, see the bash docs. Bash executes its value (or if it's an array, each of its values) before every prompt, so you can do whatever you want when `PWD` changes.

Answer (score 2):

You can add this function to your `~/.bashrc`:

```
cd () { 
    command cd "$@" &&
    if [[ $(pwd) = '/home/me/PycharmProjects/project' ]]; then
        conda activate project_venv
        export KEY=foo SECRET=bar
    fi
}
```

Comment: Tysm, it works!

Comment: I created both `../env_vars.sh` files, containing `export`s and `unset`s. [Tutorial](https://conda.io/projects/conda/en/latest/user-guide/tasks/manage-environments.html#macos-and-linux)

Comment: Instead of `export`s, could it run file: `~/miniconda3/etc/activate.d/env_vars.sh`? Then after many if statements (for many conda venvs) `else` ... `~/miniconda3/etc/deactivate.d/env_vars.sh`?

Comment: Check post for current state of implementation

Comment: @DanielBell99D Try to source it instead of running. `. ~/miniconda3/etc/activate.d/env_vars.sh`